# How to read XML file in R(in Encoding utf-8)?

Tags: xml, r, encoding

i would like to read in R an XML file with `encoding=utf-8` (there are text in Hebrew).

i know about Package XML, but i have't find in `xmlToDataFrame` any encoding options.

i've tried:

```
library(XML)
data <- xmlToDataFrame("G:/G_RBT/Alexey/DB/kupot.xml")
```

but i get problems with Hebrew, i cant read it. I also tried:

```
data <- xmlParse("G:/G_RBT/Alexey/DB/kupot.xml",encoding="UTF-8")
```

and still encoding doesn't help.

Comment: i tried  to read xml file with xmlToDataFrame, but it was problem with encoding.

Comment: You should post some code showing how far you've gone with this.

Comment: mayb this can help
`fileUrl <- "http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/_/name/bal/baltimore-ravens"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal = TRUE)
scores <- xpathSApply(doc, "//li[@class='score']", xmlValue)
teams <- xpathSApply(doc, "//li[@class='team-name']", xmlValue)`

Comment: > library(XML)
> data <- xmlToDataFrame("G:/G_RBT/Alexey/DB/kupot.xml") I tried this one, but i get problems with Hebrew, i cant read it. I tried run                                                         data <- xmlParse("G:/G_RBT/Alexey/DB/kupot.xml",encoding="UTF-8") and still encoding dont help

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need some manual elbow grease:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

# found this XML with hebrew
tmp <- GET("https://tiktickets.googlecode.com/svn-history/r102/trunk/war/ShowHalls.xml")
doc <- content(tmp, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
doc <- substr(doc, 2, nchar(doc)) # skip encoding bits at the beginning

doc_x <- xmlParse(doc, encoding="UTF-8")

# do data frame conversion by hand

data.frame(name=xpathSApply(doc_x, "//ShowHall/name", xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8"),
           address=xpathSApply(doc_x, "//ShowHall/address", xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8"),
           phone1=xpathSApply(doc_x, "//ShowHall/phone1", xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8"),
           longitude=xpathSApply(doc_x, "//ShowHall/longitude", xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8"),
           latitude=xpathSApply(doc_x, "//ShowHall/latitude", xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8"))
```